# 500 internal server error after successful WP migration

Tags: wordpress

after a successful WP migration to a new server suddenly I got an 500 internal server error without (as far as I can remember) any changes.
I get the following error log:

```
18.02.2021 20:09:43  AH02811: script not found or unable to stat: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/42/87/511174287/htdocs/xmlrpc.php
18.02.2021 20:09:43  AH02811: script not found or unable to stat: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/42/87/511174287/htdocs/wp-login.php
18.02.2021 20:24:44  AH02811: script not found or unable to stat: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/42/87/511174287/htdocs/xmlrpc.php
18.02.2021 22:08:27  AH02811: script not found or unable to stat: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/42/87/511174287/htdocs/wp-cron.php
18.02.2021 22:10:22  AH01215: PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'opcache.so' (tried: /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so (ld.so.1: php: /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so: open failed: No such file or directory), /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so.so (ld.so.1: php: /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so.so: open failed: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/42/87/511174287/htdocs/wp-cron.php
18.02.2021 22:11:39  AH01215: PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'opcache.so' (tried: /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so (ld.so.1: php: /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so: open failed: No such file or directory), /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so.so (ld.so.1: php: /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so.so: open failed: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/42/87/511174287/htdocs/wp-cron.php
18.02.2021 22:15:19  AH01215: PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'opcache.so' (tried: /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so (ld.so.1: php: /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so: open failed: No such file or directory), /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so.so (ld.so.1: php: /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so.so: open failed: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/42/87/511174287/htdocs/wp-cron.php
18.02.2021 22:17:08  AH01215: PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'opcache.so' (tried: /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so (ld.so.1: php: /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so: open failed: No such file or directory), /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so.so (ld.so.1: php: /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so.so: open failed: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/42/87/511174287/htdocs/wp-cron.php
18.02.2021 22:17:41  AH01215: PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'opcache.so' (tried: /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so (ld.so.1: php: /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so: open failed: No such file or directory), /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so.so (ld.so.1: php: /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so.so: open failed: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/42/87/511174287/htdocs/index.php
18.02.2021 22:17:44  AH01215: PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'opcache.so' (tried: /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so (ld.so.1: php: /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so: open failed: No such file or directory), /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so.so (ld.so.1: php: /opt/RZphp74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/opcache.so.so: open failed: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/42/87/511174287/htdocs/index.php
```

I've tried:

1. deactivating all plugins
2. replacing the htaccess file with the backup one and no backup file
3. replacing the database with the backup

I really have no clue what this is about. Google dosen't give me any helpfull answer besides the steps I've already tried.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share more details. If there is nothing written to the error log, you need to check whether a higher error reporting level provides more help. Additionally, unless this is related to programming itself, this is off-topic here

Comment: the same thing happened to me , if you find any solution please let me know.